# How to vertically center differently-sized hintText in TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `TextField` like this, where the input text and the hint text are sized differently.

```
TextField(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead.copyWith(
      fontSize: 70.0,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Enter a number',
      hideDivider: true,
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey[500],
        fontSize: 25.0,
      ),
    ),
);
```

While the user input text is centered in my parent container, the hintText is not (top has more space than the bottom). Is there a way to vertically center the hint text as well?

The reason the hint text is not the same size as the input text is that it takes up more space than the green Container has, so it looks like `Enter a nu...`, which isn't very user friendly. (So alternatively, is there a way to have a newline in the hintText?)

[image: Hint text is smaller so that I can fit it all in the widget]

[image: Input text is centered]

Comment: The whole TextField is already centered as a widget, I do not think there is a way to change the hint text alone, your widget is already centered what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The widget containing the input text is centered, but its accompanying hintText, which is smaller in size, is not centered. I've updated my question with a better image example. I would like the hintText `Enter a number` to be vertically centered.

Answer (score 5):

I see this is over 2 years old but in case others run into this problem:

InputDecoration has the property contentPadding.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Hint Text',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,` in your TextField.

Note: make sure you are not modifying it with other Containers or anything else & if you do then check those widgets as well.

```
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center, 
),
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: @WaheedHussain can you please share your TextField as well as the widget wrapped around the TextField code so that I can help you better?

Comment: when font size of the hint text and text is different in the textfield it does not center the text

Answer (score -1):

```
new TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'your hint',
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
)
```

`textAlign: TextAlign.center` will make your hint appear in the center.

Comment: Talking about the height

Comment: Yeah I should have clarified - I'm talking about vertical centering, not horizontal centering. I have updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the solution for your problem:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  width: 1000,
  height: 500,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    autofocus: false,
    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Email', hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff777777))),
  ),
)
```